# android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to app name

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am facing an error after adding `multidex`: `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to manifest and here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.projects.realestatefinder"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "AIzaSyBugjavAKmDVOmR0HMhD83Cyru5V0GsCro"
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "AIzaSyBugjavAKmDVOmR0HMhD83Cyru5V0GsCro"
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-async-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
compile 'com.anthonycr.grant:permissions:1.0'
  }
```

the multidex class

```
public class YouApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}

mainfest

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.projects.realestatefinder">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name="com.projects.realestatefinder.YouApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.BuiltInActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/built_in"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SettingsTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/settings"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.ImageViewerActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/view_image"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.AgentListingActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/agents"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/profile"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.PropertyResultActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/results"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.SearchResultActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/search_results"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.RegisterAgentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/register_agent"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/register"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.RealEstateEditActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/edit_real_estate"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.RealEstateAddActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/add_real_estate"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.PropertyTypeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/property_type"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.MyRealEstateActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/my_real_estates"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.MapActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/map"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.SearchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/search"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.AgentDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/agent_details"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.DetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/real_estate_details"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/login"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.projects.realestatefinder.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

</application>
```

When I am trying to run the app in android 4.4 it crashes. When I open `GPS` location I search a lot and I don't know where the problem is. Please let me know what to do to resolve this issue.

Crash logs are as follows.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.application.RealEstateApplication
                  at com.projects.fragments.MapFragment.refetch(MapFragment.java:207)
                  at com.projects.fragments.MapFragment.onMapReady(MapFragment.java:200)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                  at fs.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685003@12.6.85 (000306-197041431):20)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685003@12.6.85 (000306-197041431):5)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685003@12.6.85 (000306-197041431):5)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `com.application.RealEstateApplication` extend

`android.app.Application`

and in your manifest do:

```
android:name="com.application.RealEstateApplication"
```

And then `MultiDex.install(this);` in `onCreate()`

Comment: what you mean by extend in the mainfest or in class because i can't add both line one of them must be in mainfest com.application.RealEstateApplication extend

android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

Comment: @waleed if you want to subclass the MultiDexApplication class, you should give that class name in the manifest.

Comment: i have add `android:name".YouApplication" `      and   new class                                                                                  `public class YouApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
} ` //but it doesn't work

Comment: and also  i try to extend MultiDexApplication but nothing work

Comment: `And then MultiDex.install(this); in onCreate() ` in MainActivity or in YouApplication class that exend multidexapplication

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your Application class from MultidexApplication and use it in manifest instead of using android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication directly

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
 {
 ...
 }
```

And replace in your manifest:

```
android:name="com.projects.realestatefinder.MyApplication"
```

Comment: Your application class extends MultiDexApplication, so it should not (does not) need to call MultiDex.install(this)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, please can you also add your MapFragment ? Thank you.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285125/at-com-projects-fragments-mapfragment-refetchmapfragment-java207] i can't add more than 30k character so this the mapfragment at the link

Comment: this project with no error work fine in my pc friend he use android 5.0 via usb and iam using 4.4 this the whole diffrent

Comment: Like said in another thread :
Try to disable instant run:

   • Disable Instant run

   • Clean and rebuild the project

   • Remove the app from device and install it again without Instant run

Comment: now app work in emulator 7.0  but the gps of the emulator not work in the app so i try to run the app in  my phone android 4.4

Comment: Did you allow permission for your app to use gps on the emulator?

Comment: yes but gps so slow and it get my location amireca and iam in middle east

Comment: With the emulator you can simulate the coordinates.